# 1 light, 2 switches and 1 outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I'm adding a second switch in my hallway   The layout is power box and switch at one end, light in the middle second switch at the other end and outlet in the next room.  This is a mobile home.  Would you possibly have a wiring diagram I could use.

Comment: We're going to need more info.  Is the drywall off?  Do you have choice of cables to install?  Can you draw out where the things are (your description is ambiguous).  You can [edit] your question to add detail.

Comment: Can you run new/replacement wiring for this? Or are you limited to what's already in the wall?